# Different arguments for objective function and jacobian using sp.optimize.minimize Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, arguments, minimize

I want to optimize a function f(x,y,z) over x with sp.optimize.minimize. The Jacobian only depends on x and y, and it is the function J(x,y). (this is just a toy example)

If I try:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

def f(x,y,z):
  return(x**2+x*y**3+z)

def J(x,y):
  return(2*x+y**3)

x0,y,z=0,1,4
sp.optimize.minimize(f,x0,args=(y,z),jac=J)
```

I get an error "J() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given", because optimize passes y and z to J.

Is any way to define the arguments I want to pass to f, and the ones I want to pass to J?

(one option is to define f and J such that they have the same arguments and just ignore the ones not needed by the function, but I hope there is a more elegant way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), the Jacobian is a callable with signature

```
J(x, *args)
```

Where `args` are explicitly the fixed parameters `args=(y,z)` in your example. So **no** in general. On the other hand, nothing is preventing you from writing:

```
def J(x, y, z):
  return 2*x + y**3
```

and I do not see anything "inelegant" here. In general we write

```
df(x, y, z)/dx = f'(x, y, z)
```

anyway, and this holds for `f'` being independent of one of the variables - we do not know, and no one frowns on this sort of writing.

If you really want you could have:

```
def J(x, *args):
    return 2*x + args[0]**3
```

to hide the extra variables. I would not call this more elegant though.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed in this example allowing J to depend on z would do the job, but my case was more convoluted. My f depended on a vector theta I want to optimize for, a dataset, a moment function, and a weight matrix, while J only depends on theta and the data. I didn't want to make J to depend on other things, but it seems I will have to.